NGSPICE: How to change the label of a graph
I'm a 12th year student and I'm 17 years old. I almost finished my goal: how to create an envelope detector circuit in NGSpice. I already have the correct script and can easily plot the graph using gnuplot. However, I can't simply correctly label the graph: I just wanted to replace "tran2. v2 2" with the corresponding values ​​of each capacitor value I'm looping. Could you help me please?
this is my script

* Fonte AM com nova frequência de portadora ajustada para 100 kHz
V1 0 1 AM(0 0 100k 0.05k 1k 0 0 0)

* Modelos do diodo
.model 1N4148W D(IS=10.4n RS=51.5m BV=75.0 IBV=1.00u
     + CJO=2.00p M=0.333 N=2.07 TT=5.76n)

.model DBAT15 D(Is=1e-14 Rs=0.1 Cjo=1e-12 M=0.33
     + N=1.05 Vj=0.3 Eg=1.11)

* Componentes
D1 1 2 DBAT15
C1 2 0 0.1u
R1 2 0 10k

* Análise transiente
.tran 0.01ms 20ms

.control
    let ix = 0
    set curva = " "

    * Inicializando o gráfico
    reset
    set title "Gráfico de V(2) com Legendas para Valores de C1"
    set xlabel "Tempo (s)"
    set ylabel "Tensão (V)"
    set key outside

    * Loop para variação de C1 e geração de curvas
    foreach val 3u 6u 9u 12u 14u
        echo **************************************
        let ix = ix + 1
        echo variando para C1 = $val
        alter C1 $val
        run
        linearize
        let v_2_3 = v(2)
        set curva = ( $curva  {$curplot}.v_2_3 )
        echo índice é $&ix
        echo **************************************

        * Plotar a curva com a legenda do valor do condensador
        if $val == 3u
            plot v(2) color=yellow title "3u"
        elseif $val == 6u
            plot v(2) color=blue title "6u"
        elseif $val == 9u
            plot v(2) color=green title "9u"
        elseif $val == 12u
            plot v(2) color=red title "12u"
        elseif $val == 14u
            plot v(2) color=purple title "14u"
        end
    end

    * Configuração de saída gráfica para imagem PNG
    set xbrushwidth=2
    set gnuplot_terminal=png pngcairo transparent/quit
    set gnuplot_terminal=png size 1024,768
    set title "Gráfico de Multi-Curvas para Variação de C1"
    gnuplot circuito $curva v(1)

    * Finaliza a simulação
    quit
.endc

.end




This is the output when I plot:

Your modulated carrier is DSBSC i.e. it has a suppressed carrier (the SC part) so, what is the point of using an envelope detector (it won't properly work). Can you also explain why this is a valid EE question for this site?
